# Redux dispatcher does not change state as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning how to use Redux with React in an effort to share state across components and I've been trying to make a navigation bar that changes colors based on which div you click. At a high level I want Redux to allow me to do the following...

```
<Navigation>
  <NavEndpt /> <-- click an endpoint and you set this.props.active to true
  <NavEndpt /> <-- resets the rest and set this.props.active to false
</Navigation>
```

So basically the components change color when you click them and that is really hard to do in React, I have come to find out. I have my dispatcher wired up correctly according to the tutorial I am watching and I'm still having no success changing state.

Maybe I don't totally understand Redux. I am going to provide snippets in the order best suited for understanding of my issue and maybe you can spot where I've gone wrong.

`client.js` that gets attached to index.html nothing special.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import Layout from "./components/Layout"
import store from "./store"

const app = document.getElementById("app");

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Layout /></Provider>, app);
```

`store.js`:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";

import reducer from "./reducers/mainReducer"

export default createStore(reducer)
```

Here is `navReducer.js` that sets the initial state:

```
export default function reducer(state = {
  about: {
    id: "about",
    title: "Who I am",
    active: false
  },
  projects: {
    id: "projects",
    title: "What I do",
    active: false
  }

}, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case "CLICK": {
      return {...state, active: true }
      break
    }
  }

  return state
}
```

Here is `navActions.js` that has one action...

```
export function activeBox(){
  return{
    type: "CLICK",
  }
}
```

Here are the components that make use of the above snippets. One note, I am not receiving any errors in the console or terminal which makes me believe that my issue is simply a bad path to a file.

`Layout.js`

```
import React from "react";

import Nav from "./views/Nav"

import { connect } from "react-redux";

@connect((store) => {
  return{

      about: store.navControls.about,
      projects: store.navControls.projects

  };
})
export default class Layout extends React.Component {


  render(){

  
    return(
      <div id="wrapper">
        <Nav about={this.props.about} projects={this.props.projects} dispatch={this.props.dispatch} /> 
        <div id="content"></div>
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```

`Nav.js` (featured in `Layout`)

```
import React from "react";

import NavEndpt from "./NavEndpt"

const Nav = React.createClass({


  render(){

    let about = this.props.about;
    let projects = this.props.projects;


    return(
      <div id="navigation">
        <NavEndpt data={about} dispatch={this.props.dispatch} />
        <NavEndpt data={projects} dispatch={this.props.dispatch} />
      </div>
      )
  }
})


export default Nav;
```

and finally `NavEndpt.js`

```
import React from "react";

import { activeBox } from "../../actions/navActions.js"

const NavEndpt = React.createClass({
  handleClick(){
    let data = this.props.data;
    console.log("clicked " + data.active)
    
    this.props.dispatch(activeBox()); // this does nothing, checking out React in the chrome dev tools shows no change to about.active or projects.active
  },

  styleUpdate(){
    let data = this.props.data;

    if (data.active === false){
      return{
        background: "violet"
      }
    } else if (data.active === true){
      return {
      background: "yellow"
      }
    }
  },

  render(){
    let data = this.props.data;
    return(

      <div className="navButton" onClick={this.handleClick} style={this.styleUpdate()}>
        <span>{data.title}</span>
      </div>

      )
  }
})

export default NavEndpt;
```

Comment: You should use React Dev Tools, not just Chrome Dev Tools. Could be installed from here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/01/02/react-chrome-developer-tools.html

I suspect you'll see that your state actually does update. It becomes something like `{about:..., projects:..., active: true}`.

Comment: @EugZol I am using React Dev Tools and it does not update.

Comment: Would you mind also showing your `store.js`?

Comment: @EugZol just added it.

Comment: Why do you import `mainReducer` and creating store with it when all the action is in `navReducer`? Does `mainReducer` call `navReducer` somehow?

Comment: @EugZol yes `mainReducer` was calling `navReducer` and I was using `combine reducer` that comes with Redux. Based on our suggestion I just made store `navReducer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.props.dispatch(activeBox());` dispatches the following action to your redux store:

```
{
  type: "CLICK",
}
```

That action does not identify which nav item was clicked, it just says that a click occurred. Similarly, your reducer will go from

```
{
  about: {
    id: "about",
    title: "Who I am",
    active: false
  },
  projects: {
    id: "projects",
  title: "What I do",
  active: false
  }
}
```

to

```
{
  about: {
    id: "about",
    title: "Who I am",
    active: false
  },
  projects: {
    id: "projects",
  title: "What I do",
  active: false
  },
  active: true
}
```

You're just adding an active flag adjacent to `about` and `projects`, not in them. Check out [redux's todomvc](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todomvc/src) example to see how to best identify which item got clicked and have your store update appropriately. One solution is

```
//navActions.js
export function activeBox(nav){
  return{
    type: "CLICK",
    nav: nav
  }
}

// navReducer.js
export default function reducer(state = {
  about: {
    id: "about",
    title: "Who I am",
    active: false
  },
  projects: {
    id: "projects",
    title: "What I do",
    active: false
  }
}, action) {

switch (action.type) {
  case "CLICK": {
    // Copy state over to prevent altering previous state
    let newState = { 
      about: ...state.about,
      projects: ...state.projects
    }
    // Set all nav items to inactive, when you have more navItems you'll want to loop
    newState.about.active = false
    newState.projects.active = false

    // if action.nav is a proper nav item, set it to active
    if (newState[action.nav]) {
      newState[action.nav].active = true
    }
    return newState
    break
  }
}

return state
}
```

Comment: thank you for this thorough answer. I'm studying it now to see how to best implement your suggestion as a solution. Also thank you for the link to todomvc example- helpful resource. So I was setting some part of the store to `{active: true}` but not the part I intended, I understand that now. I see your comment at the bottom regarding `nav`  first seen in the `reducer` function but what exactly is it? Is that a reference to the `<NavEndpt />` I am clicking in order to fire off `this.props.dispatch(activeBox)`?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to dispatch an action that has the type `CLICK` as well as some identification as to which nav was clicked. I called this `nav` but it could just as easily be `navId` or whatever works best for you. In my example, you would call `this.props.dispatch(activeBox(nav))` where you're actually passing in which nav it is, either by id or by string like 'about'

Comment: I implemented your solution and it works great, thank you very much. I was trying to mess around with localStorage in order to have the app "remember" what section it is on after a refresh. Is that something better suited for react-router or is there a redux solution?

Comment: check out https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage , it's great and pretty easy to drop in